# How to return a class without array in Code Igniter

Tags: arrays, codeigniter

I have function that returns a Class in Array like this :

```php
function getInfo($ev_id){
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM events,users 
    where events.ev_user_id = users.id  
    and ev_id = $ev_id");
    $result = $query->result();
    return $result[0];        
}
```

This function returns a data Array, so I need to use the result to put it in input type to show it for user.

I need to use :-

```php
$eventinfo->ev_text
```

Not to use an fetch array to display it like `$eventinfo->ev_text`

Comment: so what exactly is the question?

Comment: you need to be clear on how many results you are expecting. if its just one result you can use $query->row() but you should confirm it with something like: if($query->num_rows() == 1 ){return $query->row();}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use

`$query->row()` instead of `$query->result()`

```
 $result = $query->row();
    return $result;
```

now you can use

```
$eventinfo->ev_text
```

with out looping